# Sort by name and rank

Tags: python, sorting

So a while ago I asked this question here: [Sorting lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732133/sorting-lists-in-python)

I have this code here:

```
def sort(names, rank):
    lst=[]
    for x in range(0, len(names)):
        lst.append((int(rank[x]), names[x]))
    lst.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[0],len(x[1])) )
    newArr = []
    for z in range(0, len(lst)):
        row = lst[z]
        newArr.append(row[1] + " " + str(row[0]))
    return newArr
```

But I also need to sort name more, if the length of the names are the same I need the one with the capital letter to come first. Any ideas?

Comment: A style hint for you: replace `for z in range(0, len(lst))` with `for row in lst`. Much simpler and more readable.

Comment: Yeah ive started to do that xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another entry into the tuple for the third condition.

```
def sort(names, rank):
    lst=[]
    for x in range(0, len(names)):
        lst.append((int(rank[x]), names[x]))
    lst.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[0],len(x[1]), ord(x[1][0])) )
    newArr = []
    for z in range(0, len(lst)):
        row = lst[z]
        newArr.append(row[1] + " " + str(row[0]))
    return newArr
```

I rewrote your code, making some style changes:

```
def sort(names, rank):
    lst=[]
    for index, name in enumerate(names):
        lst.append((int(rank[index]), name))
    lst.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[0],len(x[1]),  ord(x[1][0])))
    output = []
    for row in lst:
        output.append(row[1] + " " + str(row[0]))
    return output
```

I personally find the second approach to be a little more readable.

Comment: `sort(["fabian", "Fabian", "bob"],["1", "1", "2"])` still comes out with `fabian` before `Fabian`

Comment: Replace `x[1]` with `x[1][0]`.

Comment: Yeah, just figured that out. Thanks Mark.

Comment: Rather than using your `is_capital` function, why not use the builtin `ord` function?  e.g. `key=lambda x: (-x[0], len(x[1]), ord(x[1][0]))`  This will resort to sorting alphabetically by first letter only.  (Of course, you could just do `(-x[0], len(x[1]), x[1])` too...)

Comment: I forgot about the ord() function. Thanks.