# How can I sort a list of dictionaries by a value in the dictionary?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Python how do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/in-python-how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary)

I'm writing a Python 3.2 app and I have a list of dictionaries containing the following:

```
teamlist = [{ "name":"Bears", "wins":10, "losses":3, "rating":75.00 },
            { "name":"Chargers", "wins":4, "losses":8, "rating":46.55 },
            { "name":"Dolphins", "wins":3, "losses":9, "rating":41.75 },
            { "name":"Patriots", "wins":9, "losses":3, "rating": 71.48 }]
```

I want the list to be sorted by the values in the rating key. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I had a little bit of fun answering a similar question a while back ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/11732149/748858 ).  I discussed sorting fairly in-depth so I'll leave a link here with the hopes that it will be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/operator#operator.itemgetter) as the key:

```
sorted(teamlist, key=operator.itemgetter('rating'))
```

Comment: Do you know if there is any advantage to using `operator.itemgetter` over the `lambda` key that I use in my answer?

Comment: Thanks, this did it. Much easier than the old way I tried before using lambda and maps.

Comment: @BrendanWood -- Some people don't like `lambda`.  Also, `operator.itemgetter` is *slightly* faster -- But, probably not enough to make it worth worrying about in common situations.

Comment: @mgilson -- Thanks, I always like learning faster ways of doing things.

Comment: @BrendanWood they're equivalent, although `itemgetter` has the advantage when you want to sort by multiple keys (you can write `itemgetter(key1, key2, ...)`.  I assume it's mainly there because Guido doesn't like lambdas.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `sorted` function with a sorting key referring to whichever field you wish.

```
teamlist_sorted = sorted(teamlist, key=lambda x: x['rating'])
```

Comment: I had used this in a previous app I did but I kept getting a syntax error this time. Don't know if that was because I'm using 3.2 for this app.

Comment: @user338413: this is perfectly valid in 3.2.  You must've done something slightly different.

Comment: Yup, I just tried it myself in 3.2 and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import itemgetter
newlist = sorted(team_list, key=itemgetter('rating'))
```